# While loop in Java won't perform action on last line of document

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a text document which looks like this:

```
2 2 1 4 2 8
2 4 1 4 2 8
2 6 1 4 2 8
```

I want to find the average of all of the numbers in the second column (2,4,6).  I have written a while loop that I thought should do this.  The totalVal is the total value of all the numbers added together, and the totalNum is the total amount of numbers.

```
String line = data.nextLine();// read one line into a String

while (data.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] field = line.split(" ");
    totalVal += Double.parseDouble(field[1]);
    totalNums += 1;
    line = data.nextLine();
}   
System.out.println(totalVal / totalNums);
```

The problem is, the answer I am getting returns a value of 3, which means it is only taking the average of the first two lines of text in the document, and omitting the third.

Can somebody tell me how I can change the loop so that it adds the value in the third line of text as well?

Comment: No wonder, you're reading a line (inside the loop), then checking if there is another line after that and then handle that read line. Since there is no line after the last one, you're just ignoring it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are at the before last line, you retrieve the last line with `line = data.nextLine();` then immediatly check if `data.hasNextLine()` in the `while` loop. Since you reached the last line, this returns `false` and you exit the loop.

Change your code to:

```
while (data.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = data.nextLine();
    String[] field = line.split(" ");
    totalVal += Double.parseDouble(field[1]);
    totalNums += 1;
}
```

This first checks if there is a next line and then gets it.

And now, the super Java 8 one-liner for this:

```
double average = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
                      .mapToDouble(l -> Double.parseDouble(l.split(" ")[1]))
                      .average().orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear why you read one line before your loop.

If you read a line as the first step in your loop, then all lines will be correctly processed.

```
while (data.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = data.nextLine();
    String[] field = line.split(" ");
    totalVal += Double.parseDouble(field[1]);
    totalNums += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Believe the JVM: There's isn't a next line after you read the third line.  It stops because you told it to.

Try it like this:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * LoopDemo made to work
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810613/while-loop-in-java-wont-perform-action-on-last-line-of-document/32810646?noredirect=1#comment53458064_32810646
 * @since 9/27/2015 1:27 PM
 */
public class LoopDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner data = new Scanner(LoopDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/LoopDemo.dat"));
            double totalVal = 0.0;
            int totalNums = 0;
            String line;
            while (data.hasNextLine()) {
                line = data.nextLine();
                String[] field = line.split("\\s+");
                totalVal += Double.parseDouble(field[1]);
                totalNums += 1;
            }
            System.out.println(totalVal / totalNums);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed it.  This does it.

Answer (score 2):

If you print out `line` at the end, you'll find that the last line is in there. You captured the last line, emptying the file, and then you checked whether there were any more after you emptied it. You should either do this

```
while(data.hasNextLine())
{
    line = nextLine();
    // ...stuff...
}
```

and remove the `line = nextLine()` outside the loop or just convert this into a do-while loop.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. It should be `while(true)`. Let me fix that.

Comment: Yes, that is much better. You can clearly see _when_ the loop will stop and don't have to check the loop body for that info.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines of a document with a BufferedReader (br) like this:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
  doSomethingWith(line);
}
```

Comment: While it is true, based on fact that OP used `nextLine()` we should assume that `data` is `Scanner` not `BufferedReader` and `Scanner#nextLine()` doesn't return `null` but throws `NoSuchElementException` in case of lack of next line. Scanner gives us nice `hasNextLine()` method so we could avoid that exception and that `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` idiom.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the hint. I just wanted to show the alternative since I didn't read that he is forced to use `Scanner`.

Comment: I didn't say OP is forced to use Scanner, but generally it is easier to use it and its `next...` `hasNext...` methods instead of handling `null`s. So I won't downvote your answer as not correct (since as you mentioned it solves the problem) but I also can't upvote it because it does it in old, and possibly more little confusing way (IMO `while(scanner.hasNextLine())` is a lot easier).